# Highcharts Editor

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-editor

I'm considering buying Highcharts and I am also interested in the Editor (highcharts-editor.complete.js). But I'm unable to deduce a way to initialize the Editor with various options and data that has been previously saved.

I did notice the "Save Project" and "Open Project" buttons, but I will be integrating the editor with a database and those buttons will likely not work for me.

Update:

Thank you very much for your help Wojciech.  I did get the defaultChartOptions bits to work, but I can't seem to get the ChartChange event to kick off.  Here is the code snippet.  Thanks again!

```
function chart_changed(s)
{
    console.log(s);
}


highed.ready(function () {

    highed.Editor(document.body,

        {
            defaultChartOptions: {
                "title":{"text":"Cool Chart"},
                "subtitle":{"text":"My Cool Chart"},
                "exporting":{},
                "yAxis":[{"title":{},"labels":{}}],
                "lang":{},
                "credits":{},
                "chart":{},
                "xAxis":[{"title":{},"labels":{}}],
                "data":{"csv":"\"row\";\"val\"\n\"2013-01-01\";24\n\"2014-01-01\";76\n\"2015-01-01\";23"},
                "series":[{"data":[[1356998400000,24],[1388534400000,76],[1420070400000,23]],"name":"val","_colorIndex":0,"_symbolIndex":0}],
                "plotOptions":{"series":{"animation":false}}
            },

            on: {
                'ChartChange': 'chart_changed'
            }
        }


    );
});
```

FYI.  I've also tried:

```
            on: {
                'ChartChange': chart_changed
            }
```

And

```
highed.on('ChartChange', chart_changed);
```

And

```
highed.on('ChartChange', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please include any code you already have so that others can help address your specific issue and that future readers can better understand the problem and solution.

Comment: I edited my answer, you can check it below.

Comment: Perfect.  Works great.  Thanks Wojciech.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize editor with default options by passing them as a parameter to editor constructor:

```
{
    //The initial chart options
    defaultChartOptions: <object>,
    //Events to listen for - same as calling Editor.on(...)
    on: {
        'EventName': <function>
    },
    //Plugins to use
    plugins: {
        <name of plugin>: <object with plugin options>
    },
    //If true, an SVG chart will be inserted when exporting to provide
    //a fallback when js is not enabled/available.
    includeSVGInHTMLEmbedding: bool,
    //Features to use
    features: 'import export templates customize'
}
```

Check this github article to find more information: 
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-editor/wiki/Editor-API
**Update:**

To get `ChartChange` event to kick off you can follow this approach:

```
highed.ready(function () {
    var Editor = highed.Editor(document.body, {
        defaultChartOptions: {
            title: {
                text: 'Cool Chart!'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'My Cool Chart!'
            },
            data: {
                csv: "\"row\";\"val\"\n\"2013-01-01\";24\n\"2014-01-01\";76\n\"2015-01-01\";23"
            }
        },
        features: 'import export templates customize'
    });

    Editor.chart.on('ChartChange', function(data) {
        console.log('Chart changed! -> ', data);
    });
});
```